# What is $x$ in $-x^2+2x+3 > 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I'm busy with a homework assignment and I do not understand how I can factorize $-x^2+2x+3$.
I can't find two numbers that when multiplied make $3$, and when added make $2$. How do I solve this problem? Also one thing that confuses me is the minus sign in front of $x^2$. All the assignments in my book so far have a positive $x^2$.

Comment: $-x^2+2x+3 = -x^2+3x-x+3 = x(-x+3)+(-x+3) = (3-x)(1+x)$ as you want a product of the roots to be -3 and the sum to be 2, thus 3 and -1 will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your two confusions should cancel each other if you go from
$$ -x^2+2x+3>0$$
to
$$ x^2-2x-3<0$$

Comment: can you explain why u can change it to that formula? thanks!

Comment: Notice that $-x^2+2x+3 = -(x^2) - (-2x) - (-3) = -(x^2-2x-3)$. Now think, if you know that $-K$ is positive, it must be that $K$ is negative. Okay, so that means if $-(x^2-2x-3)>0$ then $x^2-2x-3<0$.

Comment: $>$ gives you a relative position between two numbers. Changing the sign to both is like making a reflexion on the real line with respect to the $0$. So, the number that was to the right now is to the left.

Comment: He multiplies with $(-1)$ on both sides, and therefore also has to switch the direction of the inequality. To remember this; take a simple example: $1<2$, but $-1>-2$.

Comment: @Tom Thanks, I understand it now :)

Comment: If you are uncomfortable with the argument about multiplication with $-1$ and inverting the relation, you can also add and sub to both sides: $a<b$ implies $0<b-a$ implies -b<-a$.